# SpringMVC json request validation at browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome, spring-mvc

I can see XHR requests and their responses in chrome developer tools under network tab. When a XHR call is passing a JSON in the request body, the passed parameters are visible under the form data tab under the network tab in developer tool. But it is sometimes very time consuming to find out errors in the XHR request as the request body is not shown as a json. Is there a way to see the actual JSON being passed to the server in an XHR call in chrome browser ?

Consider following scenario.

We use SpringMVC at serverend and client makes calls to server to retrieve and post requests. Assume the controller is bound with following  PersonDto.

```
PersonDto {
    String name;
    Address address;
}

AddressDto {
    String street;
    String state;
    String country;
}
```

If the client made a request with wrong json format it fails to parse the at the Controller. For eg if the client pass a json with collection of Addresses it will fail to parse the json to the above Person class. If the client and server is developed by different teams this become more tricky as these requests can not be verified as early as possible in the development.

Comment: Just do a `console.log()` with the JSON variable. %)P

Comment: I assume that you are confusing a JavaScript object (literal) with JSON and that the object is automatically encoded as form data. In hat case you never had JSON nor are you sending JSON to the server.

Comment: We use Sprint MVC at backend and in the controller a model object is bound to it and whatever the json coming as the request get automatically converted to the model by the Sprint. The issue is when the  client app send request incorrectly ( for ex sending a collection of objects where single object is expected) it fails to parse at the server. So the request should have an identical structure as the bounded model object at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Postman doesn't show me the request as a json, instead it shows it as a key value pairs as in chrome.

Comment: In Postman, select POST (or other methods, not GET), then you can edit your request Body. Instead of "form-data", check "raw, and then instead of "Text", choose "JSON (application/json)".

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler2 shows requesting json which is being sent to the server, or else you can save the XHR and use online XHR services to view it in json format.